# keep changing pointer internally to the class

Tags: c++, pointers

the best way to keep a pointer in main changes reflected inside the class?

```
static unsigned char tmp[][20] = {"hello world", "bye world"};

class X {       
    unsigned char ** buffer;

public:
    X(unsigned char* buff)
    {
        buffer = &buff;
    }

    void printThis()
    {
        DBG_MSG_FORMATED(".......> %s", *buffer);
    }
};


int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    unsigned char * buff = new unsigned char[20];
    memcpy(buff, tmp[0], 12);
    X x(buff);
    x.printThis();
    memcpy(buff, tmp[1], 12);
    x.printThis();
    delete [] buff;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

this works, but when I do the follow

```
buff = tmp[0];
x.printThis();
```

the printout doesnt print hello world again??? how to fix that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use a pointer to pointer in your class (*gulp*!):

```
class X {

    unsigned char ** buffer;

public:
    X(unsigned char** buff)
    {
        buffer = buff;
    }

    void printThis()
    {
        DBG_MSG_FORMATED(".......> %s", *buffer);
    }
};
```

And then pass in the address of the pointer during construction:

```
X x(&buff);
```

Comment: I actually just fixed it, lol, I will post my way, and mark yours as an answer

Answer (score 1):

```
int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    unsigned char * buff = new unsigned char[20];
    memcpy(buff, tmp[0], 12);
    X x(buff);
    x.printThis();
    delete [] buff;

    buff = tmp[1];  
    x.printThis();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

After you have done `delete buff;`, your pointer `buffer` in the class is pointing at memory that has been deleted, which is very bad news.

If you want to store the actual address of `buff`, you would need to pass the address of `buff` and store that, like this:

```
char **buffer;
X(unsigned char** buff)
{
    buffer = buff;
}

void printThis()
{
    DBG_MSG_FORMATED(".......> %s", *buffer);
}
```

...
    X x(&buff);

Or you could make `buffer` a reference to `buff`:

```
char*& buffer;
X(unsigned char*& buff) : buffer(buff) {}
```

(No other changes needed in class or other code - but note that you can't do `buffer = some_other_buffer;` at a later stage - that will change the value of `buff` to `some_other_buffer`, which is probably not what you expected).

Comment: Yes, but given that you overwrite the pointer with something else, you SHOULD do `delete` - what you shouldn't do is "hold on to (in this case stored in `buffer` in your class) an old pointer that has been deleted somewhere else".

Answer (score 1):

You can do something thing as bellow (using a pointer to a pointer), but sincerally, this more a problem than a solution because you are unable to delete tmp without a good care with the pointer in class X

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

static unsigned char tmp[][20] = {"hello world", "bye world"};

class X {

unsigned char ** buffer;

public:
    X(unsigned char** buff)
    {
        buffer = buff;
    }

    void printThis()
    {
        printf(".......> %s", *buffer);
    }
};


int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    unsigned char * buff = new unsigned char[20];
    memcpy(buff, tmp[0], 12);
    X x(&buff);
    x.printThis();

    buff = NULL;
    buff = tmp[1];
    x.printThis();
}
```